# Packard Bell TK11 Wifi not working (Ubuntu 12.10)

Tags: wireless, 12.10, broadcom

**Hardware:**
Packard Bell EasyNote TK11BZ, BIOS version 1.15
Broadcom BCM43227 802.11 b/n/g

**Problem:**
Everything works as it should, except the wireless connection.  The Wifi device is enabled in the "Additional Drivers" section of Software Sources, but does not even show up in the network manager drop-down.

**sudo `lshw -C` network:**

```
*-network UNCLAIMED
     description: Network controller
     product: BCM43227 802.11b/g/n
     vendor: Broadcom Corporation
     physical id: 0
     bus info: pci@0000:07:00.0
     version: 00
     width: 64 bits
     clock: 33MHz
     capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
     configuration: latency=0
     resources: memory:f0100000-f0103fff
```

Answer (score 0):

Please run:

```
    lspci -nn
```

Is the pci.id for your device 14e4:4358? If so, please get a temporary ethernet connection and do:

```
    sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic
    sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source
    sudo modprobe wl
```

If we guessed the wrong pci.id, please edit your question to add it.

Comment: That solved the problem!
The pci.id was indeed as you guessed, and the fix brought the Wifi to life.  Thank you very much!